# How to set the text of TextView based on Spinner?

Tags: java, android

My application has TextView and Spinner. Spinner contains 2 items (A and B). How do I set the text of TextView based on the selection of Spinner ? All these have to happen in one activity.

```
if(categoryType.getSelectedItem() == A){
            taxFee.setText("Total tax fee:RM" +  foodFee);
        }else{
            taxFee.setText("Total tax fee:RM" + groceryFee);
        }
```

I have tried the code above, it doesn't show the result I want. It always shows this statement `taxFee.setText("Total tax fee:RM" +  foodFee)` even if I select other category.

Comment: Just to test that your spinner is properly populated, try something like taxFee.setText(categoryType.getSelectedItem().toString()) - and see if it actually holds what you think it does - at the relevant point in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements, you can try this approach using the position:

```
categoryType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long id) {
        if(position == 0)
        {
            taxFee.setText("Total tax fee:RM" +  foodFee);
        }else{
            taxFee.setText("Total tax fee:RM" + groceryFee);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        //something
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it 
if(categoryType.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(A))

Comment: it's not changing the value of TextView as well. By the way, I am doing this in the onCreate method. Am I doing it right ?

Comment: Hi, already got the solution. Put the If Else statement into setOnItemSelectedListener

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put A in double quotes?

```
if(categoryType.getSelectedItem() == "A"){
    taxFee.setText("Total tax fee:RM" +  foodFee);
}else{
    taxFee.setText("Total tax fee:RM" + groceryFee);
}
```

or this

```
if(categoryType.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("A"))
```